# HTTPS and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ssl, https

I Just installed SSL on my server, I can access to all my folder with and without https.

Now, I put a php file on a folder. I can access to it without https, but when I want to open a secure connexion with httpS I have : 500 Internal Server Error. Only if the content of this folder is a php project, if not (e.g.: html project) it will open very well with https

I have any .htaccess on this folder.

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 just means "Something has gone wrong. The admin/developer should look in the logs". Without a real error message we can't tell you much.

Comment: Look in the server error logs - probably something went wrong with the SSL certificate.

Comment: can you show us the .htaccess

Comment: I haven't an .htaccess file. If I have to put one, what I'll put on it?

Comment: @Pekka there is my error log: SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (511) of file "/home/appfb/public_html/guerre_nord/index.php"
Premature end of script headers: index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the `Virtual Host` directive within the `httpd-ssl.conf` isn't properly configured to handle PHP files. My guess would be a **user/permission** issue or the **lack of a handler directive** that would tell Apache how to handle .php files.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure you htaccess properly, by that i mean to get it on.